# I have a list of excel filenames in the column A of my worksheet and I would like to remove the .xls and .xlsm tags from the filenames using VBA. How?

Tags: vba, excel

[I want to remove the .xls and .xlsm tags using the "." in the VBA
    logic, but I am a beginner in VBA and I am wondering how I can
    accomplish the objective ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd0r6.png)

Comment: google `vba split command`

Comment: Thanks for the response, In this case I am interested only in splitting and removing the text after the last "." character

Comment: Then read the documentation on the `split` command, all the information you need to solve your problem is there. If, after thoroughly researching your issue, you are still having a specific problem, please share with us your code with a [MCVE] and the part you are not understanding and the research you have done, that way we can know what you really need.

Comment: You dont even need the split command for this. Just replace the text. VBA is overkill for this task, to say the least. If you dont know how to solve the problem in VBA on your own, you would be best off becoming more comfortable in Excel first before getting into the ring with VBA which can be quite unruly for beginners.

Comment: Also, to point you in the right direction, the Excel formula `=SUBSTITUTE(text, old_text, new_text)` would be sufficient. If you want to be precise about the positioning of the filepath separator use a combination of `SEARCH` and `LEFT`. Here's some documentation on the former approach: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-substitute-function.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it... Just pass in the range that you want to extract from

```
Sub RemoveExtension(rng As Range)
   ' Declare your variables
   Dim LR As Long
   Dim i As Long
   Dim str() As String

   With rng
      ' Find the last row
      LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
      ' Enter loop
      For i = LR To 1 Step -1
         If Not (IsEmpty(.Cells(i))) Then
            ' Extract and split text using "." as a delimiter
            str() = Split(.Cells(i).Value, ".")
            ' Rewrite text in cell from first array variable in str()
            .Cells(i).Value = str(0)
         End If
      Next i
   End With
End Sub
```

You can call this function with another `Sub` function... Example below:

```
Sub Macro1()

    ' Change Range() to what every range you need
    Call RemoveExtension(Range("A2:A10"))

End Sub
```

Bare in mind this only works on columns, so you cannot pass in `Range("A1:C3")`

Comment: Sub RemoveExtension(rng As A2)
   ' Declare your variables
   Dim LR As Long
   Dim i As Long
   Dim str() As String

   With rng
      ' Find the last row
      LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
      ' Enter loop
      For i = LR To 1 Step -1
         If Not (IsEmpty(.Cells(i))) Then
            ' Extract and split text using "." as a delimiter
            str() = Split(.Cells(i).Value, ".")
            ' Rewrite text in cell from first array variable in str()
            .Cells(i).Value = str(0)
         End If
      Next i
   End With
End Sub

Comment: Since the data I am working on is in the A column I gave the range value as A2 as you see in the code. But the code doesn't work unfortunately. Let me know if you have any comments.

Comment: All you need to do is call this function... You shouldn't have to modify anything.

Comment: Take a look at [VBA Function Calling](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/function-sub.html) if you don't understand